# Highlighting rows and columns by ActiveCell in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is create a VBA macro which highlights rows and columns by `ActiveCell`, so I programmed the following code:

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function

Public Sub SetCellPosition()
    Dim currentActiveCellAdress, columnLetter, rowRangeAddress, columnRangeAddress, selectionRangeAdress As String
    Dim rowNumber As Long

    columnLetter = Col_Letter(ActiveCell.Column)
    rowNumber = ActiveCell.Row

    rowRangeAddress = columnLetter & "1:" & columnLetter & rowNumber
    columnRangeAddress = "A" & rowNumber & ":" & columnLetter & rowNumber
    currentActiveCellAdress = ActiveCell.Address
    selectionRangeAdress = rowRangeAddress & ", " & columnRangeAddress

    Debug.Print selectionRangeAdress
    Debug.Print currentActiveCellAdress

    Range(selectionRangeAdress).Select
    Range(currentActiveCellAdress).Activate

End Sub
```

That macro works well. But after calling that macro by `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange`

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Call SetCellPosition
End Sub
```

it gives me an error, selection in sheet flashes between highlighting rows and columns by `ActiveCell` and first row, please see the pictures.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The macro can be downloaded [here](https://www.janzitniak.info/subory/highlighting-rows-and-columns-by-activecell.xlsm).

Kind regards.

Jan

Comment: When it faiils, what is the value of `selectionRangeAdress`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you call this macro in a `SelectionChange` event. However this line:

```
Range(selectionRangeAdress).Select
```

Counts as a `SelectionChange` event, meaning it will call this macro. This means you call this macro within the macro, resulting in a recursive function until you run out of stack space and it errors out. To prevent this, add `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the start, and `True` at the end. This prevents any events firing while the macro runs, thus preventing the function to call itself in the middle of it.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
    Call SetCellPosition
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Plutian, now it works. I tried Application.EnableEvents = False and Application.EnableEvents = True before but Workbook_SheetSelectionChange stayed in previous infinite state so I had to restart Excel for working.